# Simple python connection to Traci

Tags: python, tensorflow, sumo

I’m trying to connect to Traci-Server within my Conda environment (Conda is needed for my Tensorflow project) that I intend to interface with SUMO Traffic Simulator

```
import os, sys

if 'SUMO_HOME' in os.environ:
 tools = os.path.join(os.environ['SUMO_HOME'], 'tools')
 sys.path.append(tools)
else:
 sys.exit("please declare environment variable 'SUMO_HOME'")

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

import traci                    #TraCI functionality
from sumolib import checkBinary #checkBinary help locate the Sumo binaries
import time


traci.connect()
traci.start(['sumo-gui', '-c', 'osm.sumocfg', "--start", "--quit-on-end"])

traci.close()
```

However, I’m getting Connection errors

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\.conda\envs\tf\python.exe "C:/Users/<UserName>/PycharmProjects/Tensor Tutorial/TestTraffic.py"
 Retrying in 1 seconds
Could not connect to TraCI Server at localhost:8813 [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machines actively refused it
 Retrying in 1 seconds
Could not connect to TraCI Server at localhost:8813 [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machines actively refused it
 Retrying in 1 seconds
Could not connect to TraCI Server at localhost:8813 [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machines actively refused it
 Retrying in 1 seconds
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program_Files_(x86)\Eclipse\Sumo\tools\traci\main.py", line 166, in connect
   conn = Connection(host, port, proc)
  File "C:\Program_Files_(x86)\Eclipse\Sumo\tools\traci\main.py", line 51, in __init__
   self._socket.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/<UserName>/PycharmProjects/Tensor Tutorial/TestTraffic.py", line 24, in <module>
   traci.connect()
  File "C:\Program_Files_(x86)\Eclipse\Sumo\tools\traci\main.py", line 127, in connect
   time.sleep(waitBetweenRetries)
KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please include the code and traceback as text, not an image. Make sure the code is a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just leave out the traci.connect. It is not needed if you use traci.start.

Comment: New error has appeared when I removed `traci.connect()`
```C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\Sumo\tools\traci\main.py:174: UserWarning: Could not connect to TraCI server using port 62584 (TraCI server already finished). Retrying with different port.
  " Retrying with different port.") % (sumoPort, e))```

Comment: Turns out the configuration files must be relative to the file directory